# How to send strings from a PHP-server to an Objective-C client?

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa

I've got a server on which I can run PHP scripts and an application which is written in Objective-C and Cocoa.

What's the easiest way to send multiple strings (in my case 4) from the server to the client?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest methods for receiving data/strings from the web:

For pure data:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
```

For an actual string:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Could not receive string: %@", error);
}
```

These two calls fire a **synchronous request**, blocking your thread.
For asynchronous non-blocking requests read Apple's [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) for full instructions.